# Merging column data

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Name, Members 
FROM People 
WHERE Name LIKE '%Kako%' 
GROUP BY Name, Members
```

I am getting this result from the SQL query shown above:

```
Name        |   Members
------------+-------------
James Kako  |   Rangers
James Kako  |   Wind
James Kako  |   Poers
James Kako  |   Lohe
James Kako  |   Jubo
J. Kako     |   Wind
J. Kako     |   Lohe
J. Kako     |   Poers
```

I would like to merge `Members` column like this:

```
Name        | Members
------------+---------------------------------
James Kako  | Rangers, Wind, Poers, Lohe, Jubo
J. Kako     | Wind, Lohe, Poers
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv

Comment: Please change the order of `GROUP BY` and `WHERE` in your SQL , respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `STRING_AGG` is the direct way for this type of problems :

```
SELECT Name, STRING_AGG(Members, ', ') as Members
  FROM People
 WHERE Name LIKE '%Kako%'
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name DESC;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9c0d3/3)

Comment: Teşekkürler. Aslında gerçek veriler çoklu sonuç veriyor. Yani James Kako  |   Rangers kayıdından onlarca veri var. Bu verileri sub query'ler ile DISTINCT ettim. Acaba önerebileceğiniz daha sağlıklı bir yöntem var mıdır?

Comment: Teşekkür ederim. İyi çalışmalar.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works as well:

```
DECLARE @char VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @char = COALESCE(@char + ', ' + members, members) 
FROM MergeColumn ;
Select name , @char as Mergerd from MergeColumn group by name;
```

Also, you can take a look at this link for more solutions to the question you asked: [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)